# Error handling when an account is not validated

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a Reactjs project with a Login/Register part.

When an user is registered, an email is sent to his email with a link to confirm his account.

I want to display an error when an user tries to login while not validated.

I have an error in the backend part but I don't know how to handle this in the front part.

**My code**

**Front (Submit button)**

```
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    login(user).then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
      } else {
        toast.error("Please verify your email or password", {
          position: "bottom-center",
          autoClose: 2500,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**Login function**

```
export const login = user => {
  return axios
    .post(API_URL + "/users/login", {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem("usertoken", response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**Back code**

```
export const loginUser = (req, res) => {
  // Check if the email already exists
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        // Check if the password is correct
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          // Create a token
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          });
          if (!user.active)
            res
              .status(400)
              .json({ error: "Your account has not been verified." });
          else res.send(token);
        } else {
          res.status(400).json({ error: "Password is incorrect" });
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "User does not exist" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    });
};
```

As you can see in the backend, active is a boolean that is false until the user has confirmed his account by clicking on the link, then active is true.

Comment: what is the error you're getting when trying to login ?

Comment: In the backend I got the error "Your account has not been verified" but in the front I got the toast "Please verify your email or password" because I can't login

Comment: in front end `login` function what is the response you're getting

Comment: `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: i guess you're getting valid response right? which you're sending from BE when account is not active

Comment: can you update you're question with `res` object from login function

Comment: What do you want to know ? the `res` object is the token when I log in. When I try to log in without email validation `res` is undefined.

Comment: i want to know what response you're getting in login api call

Comment: When I try to login without email validation I got the error 400 and the message "Your account has not been verified". Is that you wanted to know ?

Comment: yes! that is desired result right? what is the error in that? As `user` is not active you're getting that error.

Comment: I want to display it using toastify to the frontend to notify the user.

Comment: have you tried it like this `toast.error(res.error, STYLES_OBJECT });`

Comment: `res.error` instead of `Please verify your email or password` ? I got an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

Comment: you mentioned you're getting error property in `res` object ?

Comment: If I add a `console.log(res)` after my toast.error I got undefined. It explains the error above

Comment: can you show what you're getting in `response.data` in login function

Comment: This is the token string.